# Can it hurt to upgrade Windows 7 drivers?

Tags: bootcamp, driver

I was running into issues playing Starcraft 2 on Windows 7 (32 bits): once in a while, the game would unexpectedly quit with "Core: out of memory" as the error message. [I went to the Blizzard support forum with this problem](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2456725696), and they told me that my video and sound drivers are outdated by a year or two.

Notwithstanding that I'm not sure how these drivers can impact the memory usage of the game, I don't know if upgrading is a good idea. I'm quite sure that it won't hurt the Mac OS side of my computer if I do (as the Blizzard rep suggested to double-check), but said drivers seem to come from Apple, and I'm not sure if my Mac would behave well if I upgraded them.

Has anyone tried to upgrade the sound and video drivers for Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - No, it won't hurt.  But it may not work.  As with any driver upgrade there is no guarantees.  But there is no harm in trying.  You can always revert back if it doesn't work.

If you find it doesn't work, hold F8 whilst booting into Windows to prompt you to boot into safe-mode.  When in safe mode you can revert your video driver.

Let us know how it works out.  I doubt you're the only person playing SC2 on Windows on a Mac ;)